# what is the max file size we can upload using php?

Tags: php, file, upload, size

I want to upload files on my website. I have read at a few places that 10MB is the max upload size of a file using php. Can we increase the size of file to 25MB? If yes, how can i go about doing it. What settings i need to change?

Thanks,
-B

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things you need to check in PHP.ini:

- post_max_size
- upload_max_filesize

You can easily increase these to 25MB and beyond.  I've done it with gigs before, no issues.  Also keep in mind any web server limitations that may be configured.  IIS7 by default has a 30MB limit, for example.

Comment: Hi Brad,I tried your suggestion but the php.ini file does not have either of these variables. Can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: @user847452, then add them.  See Marc's link:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

Answer (score -3):

Every hosting provider has diffent values for the uploaded file.
If you have a own server, well i think its the size of the memory in the server.
So 4GB of memory is around 2-3GB upload, or just use a flash/java uploader :)

Comment: Memory capacity is not the only thing to think about.  Apache and PHP both have configuration options (as pointed out by Brad) that need looked at